# Adding to a string with a While Loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am trying to concatenate a string to another string until the last value is reached:

```
var z = 0;
while(z < columns.length) { 
    url = url + delimiter;
    z++;
    break;
}
```

This however seems to add my delimiter to the very end of my url, how can this be fixed?

e.g.
what I want:

```
 url|dilimeter|url|dilimeter|url
```

what I get:

```
 url|dilimeter|url|dilimeter|url|dilimiter
```

Note: I have the break statement because this is inside a for loop

Comment: z can start with 1. var z=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
var z = 0;
var urlParts = [];

while(z < columns.length) { 
    urlParts.push( url );
    z++;
    break;
}

url = urlParts.join( delimiter );
```